# Algorítimo que ordene números decimais

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Galera quem poder me ajudar fico extremamente grato, estou tentando construir um algorítimo que ordene 3 valores numéricos reais em ordem crescente, mas não se como lidar com números decimais no algorítimo...

```
var 

num: vetor[1..3] de inteiro
i, j, aux: inteiro

Inicio

 para i de 1 ate 3 passo 1 faca
      escreva ("Informe um número:")
      leia (num[i])
 fimpara

      para i de 1 ate 2 passo 1 faca
           para j de i+1 ate 3 faca
                se (num[i] > num[j]) entao
                   aux <- num[i]
                   num[i] <- num[j]
                   num[j] <- aux
                fimse
           fimpara
      fimpara

      para i de 1 ate 3 passo 1 faca
           escreva (num[i])
      fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Você está programando em qual ambiente?

Comment: Sendo mais especifico, é um trabalho da faculdade, estou usando o Portugol (português estruturado).
Em outras linguagens de programação poderia usar o comando sort(), mas como o mesmo não existe no portugol preciso construir algo com este objetivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua:

```
num: vetor[1..3] de inteiro
```

por:

```
num: vetor[1..3] de real
```

e coloque a variável aux também como real:

```
aux: real
```

Comment: Cara, me salvou haha muitíssimo obrigado !